# Default Registry Values for Startup in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry

I followed the guide [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/shortcuts-in-the-startup-folder-not-running-during/646845d6-8c10-4456-b6ef-b99f4a03aa10) to try resolve a problem with some shortcuts not working on startup, but forgot to create a backup of those registry keys, and now want to revert the change. Is there a way to see the default, preset values for registry keys, specifically the ones under:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders
```

For both **Startup** and **Common Startup**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it may help, here are the requested values from my computer:

**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders]
"Startup"=hex(2):25,00,55,00,53,00,45,00,52,00,50,00,52,00,4f,00,46,00,49,00,\
  4c,00,45,00,25,00,5c,00,41,00,70,00,70,00,44,00,61,00,74,00,61,00,5c,00,52,\
  00,6f,00,61,00,6d,00,69,00,6e,00,67,00,5c,00,4d,00,69,00,63,00,72,00,6f,00,\
  73,00,6f,00,66,00,74,00,5c,00,57,00,69,00,6e,00,64,00,6f,00,77,00,73,00,5c,\
  00,53,00,74,00,61,00,72,00,74,00,20,00,4d,00,65,00,6e,00,75,00,5c,00,50,00,\
  72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,73,00,5c,00,53,00,74,00,61,00,72,00,74,\
  00,75,00,70,00,00,00
```

**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders]
"Common Startup"=hex(2):25,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,44,00,\
  61,00,74,00,61,00,25,00,5c,00,4d,00,69,00,63,00,72,00,6f,00,73,00,6f,00,66,\
  00,74,00,5c,00,57,00,69,00,6e,00,64,00,6f,00,77,00,73,00,5c,00,53,00,74,00,\
  61,00,72,00,74,00,20,00,4d,00,65,00,6e,00,75,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,\
  00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,73,00,5c,00,53,00,74,00,61,00,72,00,74,00,75,00,70,00,\
  00,00
```